# findOneAndRemove deletes wrong user when I pass 962122961v it will delete 962122963v

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
router.delete('/user/:userId', (req ,res) => {
    User.findOneAndRemove(req.params.userId, (err, doc) => {
        if(!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else {console.log('Error in Insurance agent Delete :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`findOneAndRemove()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) method needs an object as query parameter. So instead of:

```
User.findOneAndRemove(req.params.userId, (err, doc) => {
```

Use this:

```
User.findOneAndRemove({userId: req.params.userId}, (err, doc) => {
```